# Trigger para recuperar Último Registro Inserido na tabela em PL-SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql, trigger

Tenho uma trigger que apos ser inserido um novo usuario na tabela tFuncionario devo preencher outra tabela tPlanoSaude com os dados do funcionario.

tabela Funcionario

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

tabela Plano de Saúde

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Codigo da Trigges**

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INSERTFUNCIONARIO 
    BEFORE INSERT ON tfuncionario 
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO tPlanoSaude VALUES(
          :old.TFUNCIONARIO.MATRICULA,
          :old.TFUNCIONARIO.NOME);
    END;
```

**Mensagem de erro:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Inclua a linha FOR EACH ROW na linha abaixo do BEFORE.

Comment: Perfeito. funcioando!

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INSERTFUNCIONARIO 
BEFORE INSERT ON tfuncionario 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tPlanoSaude VALUES(:new.matricula,:new.MATRICULA);
END;

Comment: acrescentei as palavras reservadas :new. antes das colunas para quais quero recuperar o valor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variável `:NEW` e `:OLD` já é a tabela em sí com os dados do inserted e deleted respectivamente, não é neecssário passar a tabela: `:NEW.TABELA.CAMPO`

Somente `:NEW.CAMPO`, onde `:NEW` já refere-se a sua tabela.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui executar a trigger com este trecho de código:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INSERTFUNCIONARIO 
BEFORE INSERT ON tfuncionario 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tPlanoSaude VALUES(:new.matricula,:new.MATRICULA);
END;
```